# Setting a class property on a long running thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, threadpool

I am populating some class properties,

One of them involves serializing an Entity structure to a byte[] this takes some time so I wanted to do it in a thread.

The value never gets set as I assume the class and thread are now out of scope.

The code is below, any ideas would be appreciated

```
   public class classA
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var classC = new ClassB().DoSomethingElse();

        //SAVE CLASS c to database
        var serialized = classC.GetSerializedDataTable(); // is always null unless i take out the task from class c
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassC DoSomethingElse()
    {
        var classC = new ClassC();

        classC.DataTableValue = new DataTable();
        classC.SerializeToByteArray();
        return classC;
    }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public DataTable DataTableValue { get; set; }
    private byte[] serializedData;


    public void SerializedDataTable()
    {
        new Task(() => this.serializedData = this.DataTableValue.SerializeToByteArray()).Start();
    }


    public byte[] GetSerializedDataTable()
    {
        return this.serializedData;
    }

}
```

Comment: Quite a bit of code but still incomplete.

Comment: Hi Henk, yes i just did this as a pseudo code example, my code it much more than this but essentially this gives the background to what i am doing, basically i kick off the task and when i try to save the desirialized value, its always null,  probably because the task and class have become out of scope? when i take out the task it obviously works...

Comment: I can't tell. Too much pseudo isn't good. And how do you know the Task has completed?

Comment: I don't monitor the task is complete, but basically it takes 90 milliseconds and the code after that takes about 200ms, so it has lots of time to complete, but before it completes i think the task has been gobbled by the GC already, as the value is always saved as null... if i put in a wait in the ClassC - SerializedDataTable of about 100ms then it works... but that doesnt help me then as i lose the advantage of the thread...

Comment: If you need the value before continuing then you have to wait for the thread to finish thus making the thread pointless.

Comment: Hi Alex, i need the thread to finish before I save in classA, i have more than enough time +- 200ms before the save completes, the task takes 90ms. The problem is the time taken to complete is in ClassA and not ClassC, is there anyway to sync up the threads before saving?

Comment: or is it to late as soon as I finish in classC is the thread lost?

Comment: You should check whether the task completed in `GetSerializedDataTable()` before returning `byte[]`. If you are saying task has enough time to complete then this should not be  a big performance hit (blocking for too long).

Comment: thanks YK1 thats what i will do!

Answer (score 0):

A `Task` is not just meant to be used to run code on another thread, it represents a logical unit of work that can return something once it is complete.

Your `ClassC.GetSerializedDataTable()` appears to be a perfect place to make use of a `Task<byte[]>` return type:

```
public class ClassC
{
    public DataTable DataTableValue { get; set; }
    private Task<byte[]> serializeDataTask;

    public void SerializeDataTable()
    {
        serializeDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => this.DataTableValue.SerializeToByteArray() );
    }

    public Task<byte[]> GetSerializedDataTable()
    {
        // You can either throw or start it lazily if SerializeDataTable hasnt been called yet.
        if ( serializeDataTask == null ) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return serializeDataTask;
    }
}
```

And now your client code can utilize the Task return type in intelligent ways. If the result is already available, it can consume it immediately via Task.Result. Otherwise it can wait for it to complete, or perform some other work until it completes. The point is the calling code now has the context to take the most appropriate course of action.

Back to your example:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    var classC = new ClassB().DoSomethingElse();

    //SAVE CLASS c to database
    var serializeTask = classC.GetSerializedDataTable();
    // will obtain result if available, will block current thread and wait for serialized data if task still running.
    var serializedData = serializeTask.Result; 
}
```